# Maven Multi-Module clean cannot find dependency

Tags: java, maven, multi-module

## Problem

`mvn package` is successful but `mvn clean` fails due to dependency artifact not being found in a multi-module project.

### Details

I am new to Maven and thus far my Google foo has not been successful.  I'm attempting to learn it through a pet project and its mostly coming along fine.  I am attempting to use Maven to build both a custom plugin and my main App at the same time.  Both are currently generic having been build using the `mvn archetype:generate` for a plugin and a quickstart. Thus far, running `mvn package` works just fine. I can see my plugin being built, and during the process of building my main App, my plugin is executed. This is exactly what I wanted to see. The resulting jar from the main app works fine and the *touch.txt* file that the sample plugin generates is also present.

However, when I attempt `mvn clean`, maven reactor cleans up my plugin first, so when it then cleans up my main App it can't locate the plugin's jar file that it just deleted in the previous step and fails. I can't find where I should specify this order as I thought reactor was supposed to figure this out on its own. Then again, maybe the main App shouldn't be looking for the plugin jar at all.  Do I need to exclude it during one of the phases? I've attempted swapping the order of the modules by changing their order in my parent *pom.xml* file and that didn't seem to make a difference but I also don't know if I need to clear out a cache before the swap would have any effect. I feel like I'm missing something fundamental here in my understanding of Maven.  Either way, overly verbose details are below and any help would be greatly appreciated.

`mvn --version`:

```
Apache Maven 3.6.3
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 13.0.7, vendor: Private Build, runtime: /usr/lib/jvm/java-13-openjdk-amd64
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "5.15.5-76051505-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

#### Project Directory Structure

Before anything is built:

```
maven-test
    ├── build-args
    │   ├── pom.xml
    │   └── src
    │       ├── it
    │       │   ├── settings.xml
    │       │   └── simple-it
    │       │       ├── pom.xml
    │       │       └── verify.groovy
    │       ├── main
    │       │   └── java
    │       │       └── com
    │       │           └── ecorp
    │       │               └── MyMojo.java
    │       └── test
    │           ├── java
    │           │   └── com
    │           │       └── ecorp
    │           │           └── MyMojoTest.java
    │           └── resources
    │               └── project-to-test
    │                   └── pom.xml
    ├── call-me
    │   ├── pom.xml
    │   └── src
    │       ├── main
    │       │   └── java
    │       │       └── com
    │       │           └── ecorp
    │       │               └── App.java
    │       └── test
    │           └── java
    │               └── com
    │                   └── ecorp
    │                       └── AppTest.java
    └── pom.xml
```

After Build

```
maven-test
    ├── build-args
    │   ├── pom.xml
    │   ├── src
    │   │   ├── it
    │   │   │   ├── settings.xml
    │   │   │   └── simple-it
    │   │   │       ├── pom.xml
    │   │   │       └── verify.groovy
    │   │   ├── main
    │   │   │   └── java
    │   │   │       └── com
    │   │   │           └── ecorp
    │   │   │               └── MyMojo.java
    │   │   └── test
    │   │       ├── java
    │   │       │   └── com
    │   │       │       └── ecorp
    │   │       │           └── MyMojoTest.java
    │   │       └── resources
    │   │           └── project-to-test
    │   │               └── pom.xml
    │   └── target
    │       ├── build-args-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
    │       ├── classes
    │       │   ├── com
    │       │   │   └── ecorp
    │       │   │       ├── HelpMojo.class
    │       │   │       └── MyMojo.class
    │       │   └── META-INF
    │       │       └── maven
    │       │           ├── com.ecorp
    │       │           │   └── build-args
    │       │           │       └── plugin-help.xml
    │       │           └── plugin.xml
    │       ├── generated-sources
    │       │   ├── annotations
    │       │   └── plugin
    │       │       └── com
    │       │           └── ecorp
    │       │               └── HelpMojo.java
    │       ├── generated-test-sources
    │       │   └── test-annotations
    │       ├── maven-archiver
    │       │   └── pom.properties
    │       ├── maven-plugin-help.properties
    │       ├── maven-status
    │       │   └── maven-compiler-plugin
    │       │       ├── compile
    │       │       │   └── default-compile
    │       │       │       ├── createdFiles.lst
    │       │       │       └── inputFiles.lst
    │       │       └── testCompile
    │       │           └── default-testCompile
    │       │               ├── createdFiles.lst
    │       │               └── inputFiles.lst
    │       ├── surefire-reports
    │       │   ├── com.ecorp.MyMojoTest.txt
    │       │   └── TEST-com.ecorp.MyMojoTest.xml
    │       └── test-classes
    │           ├── com
    │           │   └── ecorp
    │           │       ├── MyMojoTest$1.class
    │           │       └── MyMojoTest.class
    │           └── project-to-test
    │               ├── pom.xml
    │               └── target
    │                   └── touch.txt
    ├── call-me
    │   ├── pom.xml
    │   ├── src
    │   │   ├── main
    │   │   │   └── java
    │   │   │       └── com
    │   │   │           └── ecorp
    │   │   │               └── App.java
    │   │   └── test
    │   │       └── java
    │   │           └── com
    │   │               └── ecorp
    │   │                   └── AppTest.java
    │   └── target
    │       ├── call-me-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
    │       ├── classes
    │       │   └── com
    │       │       └── ecorp
    │       │           └── App.class
    │       ├── generated-sources
    │       │   └── annotations
    │       ├── generated-test-sources
    │       │   └── test-annotations
    │       ├── maven-archiver
    │       │   └── pom.properties
    │       ├── maven-status
    │       │   └── maven-compiler-plugin
    │       │       ├── compile
    │       │       │   └── default-compile
    │       │       │       ├── createdFiles.lst
    │       │       │       └── inputFiles.lst
    │       │       └── testCompile
    │       │           └── default-testCompile
    │       │               ├── createdFiles.lst
    │       │               └── inputFiles.lst
    │       ├── surefire-reports
    │       │   ├── com.ecorp.AppTest.txt
    │       │   └── TEST-com.ecorp.AppTest.xml
    │       ├── test-classes
    │       │   └── com
    │       │       └── ecorp
    │       │           └── AppTest.class
    │       └── touch.txt
    └── pom.xml

71 directories, 40 files
pizza@hut:~/maven/maven-test$ java -jar call-me/target/call-me-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar 
Hello World!
pizza@hut:~/maven/maven-test$ cat call-me/target/touch.txt 
touch.txt
```

### Package

If I manually clean everything up by deleting all of the target folders and then run `mvn package`:

```
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO] 
[INFO] maven-test                                                         [pom]
[INFO] build-args Maven Plugin                                   [maven-plugin]
[INFO] call-me                                                            [jar]
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------< com.ecorp:maven-test >------------------------
[INFO] Building maven-test 1.0-SNAPSHOT                                   [1/3]
[INFO] --------------------------------[ pom ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------< com.ecorp:build-args >------------------------
[INFO] Building build-args Maven Plugin 1.0-SNAPSHOT                      [2/3]
.........
[INFO] Building call-me 1.0-SNAPSHOT                                      [3/3]
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- build-args:1.0-SNAPSHOT:touch (default) @ call-me ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.0.2:resources (default-resources) @ call-me ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /somepath/maven-test/call-me/src/main/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) @ call-me ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to /somepath/maven-test/call-me/target/classes
.........
[INFO] Reactor Summary for maven-test 1.0-SNAPSHOT:
[INFO] 
[INFO] maven-test ......................................... SUCCESS [  0.005 s]
[INFO] build-args Maven Plugin ............................ SUCCESS [  4.101 s]
[INFO] call-me ............................................ SUCCESS [  0.574 s]
```

### Clean

`mvn clean` exert:

```
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO] 
[INFO] maven-test                                                         [pom]
[INFO] build-args Maven Plugin                                   [maven-plugin]
[INFO] call-me                                                            [jar]
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------< com.ecorp:maven-test >------------------------
[INFO] Building maven-test 1.0-SNAPSHOT                                   [1/3]
[INFO] --------------------------------[ pom ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:3.1.0:clean (default-clean) @ maven-test ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------< com.ecorp:build-args >------------------------
[INFO] Building build-args Maven Plugin 1.0-SNAPSHOT                      [2/3]
[INFO] ----------------------------[ maven-plugin ]----------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:3.1.0:clean (default-clean) @ build-args ---
[INFO] Deleting /somepath/maven-test/build-args/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------------------------< com.ecorp:call-me >--------------------------
[INFO] Building call-me 1.0-SNAPSHOT                                      [3/3]
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary for maven-test 1.0-SNAPSHOT:
[INFO] 
[INFO] maven-test ......................................... SUCCESS [  0.159 s]
[INFO] build-args Maven Plugin ............................ SUCCESS [  0.030 s]
[INFO] call-me ............................................ FAILURE [  0.005 s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  0.303 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-12-29T12:29:55-05:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Plugin com.ecorp:build-args:1.0-SNAPSHOT or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact com.ecorp:build-args:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]
```

### POM Files

#### Parent

Here is a copy of my maven-test *pom.xml* file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.ecorp</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-test</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>maven-test</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>
      
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>
  
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
      
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  
  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
          <configuration>
            <archive>
              <manifest>
                <mainClass>com.ecorp.App</mainClass>
              </manifest>
            </archive>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.7.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
    
  <modules>
    <module>call-me</module>
    <module>build-args</module>
  </modules>
  
</project>
```

#### Plugin

Here is a copy of my build-args plugin *pom.xml*:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  
  <parent>
    <artifactId>maven-test</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.ecorp</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>

  <groupId>com.ecorp</groupId>
  <artifactId>build-args</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>maven-plugin</packaging>

  <name>build-args Maven Plugin</name>

  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <prerequisites>
    <maven>${maven.version}</maven>
  </prerequisites>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.version>3.3.9</maven.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-plugin-api</artifactId>
      <version>${maven.version}</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-core</artifactId>
      <version>${maven.version}</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-artifact</artifactId>
      <version>${maven.version}</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-compat</artifactId>
      <version>${maven.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency> 
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugin-tools</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-plugin-annotations</artifactId>
      <version>3.6.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.12</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugin-testing</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-plugin-testing-harness</artifactId>
      <version>3.3.0</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-plugin-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <!-- <goalPrefix>maven-archetype-plugin</goalPrefix> -->
          <skipErrorNoDescriptorsFound>true</skipErrorNoDescriptorsFound>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>mojo-descriptor</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>descriptor</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>help-goal</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>helpmojo</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>run-its</id>
      <build>

        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-invoker-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <configuration>
              <debug>true</debug>
              <cloneProjectsTo>${project.build.directory}/it</cloneProjectsTo>
              <pomIncludes>
                <pomInclude>*/pom.xml</pomInclude>
              </pomIncludes>
              <postBuildHookScript>verify</postBuildHookScript>
              <localRepositoryPath>${project.build.directory}/local-repo</localRepositoryPath>
              <settingsFile>src/it/settings.xml</settingsFile>
              <goals>
                <goal>clean</goal>
                <goal>test-compile</goal>
              </goals>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>integration-test</id>
                <goals>
                  <goal>install</goal>
                  <goal>integration-test</goal>
                  <goal>verify</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
</project>
```

#### Main App

Here is a copy of my call-me *pom.xml* main app:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <artifactId>maven-test</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.ecorp</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>

  <groupId>com.ecorp</groupId>
  <artifactId>call-me</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>call-me</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.ecorp</groupId>
      <artifactId>build-args</artifactId>
      <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  
  <build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>com.ecorp</groupId>
      <artifactId>build-args</artifactId>
      <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <goals>
            <goal>touch</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Could you try `mvn install` instead of `mvn package` and then run `mvn clean`?

Comment: @The5thcolumnmouse That works.  I can't believe I didn't think of that.  For whatever reason, I didn't think `mvn install` would also build my main app but it does.  Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome! It is not enough to build the artifact, you have to install it into the local `.m2` repository.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by @The5thcolumnmouse, instead of using `mvn package`, if I use `mvn install` then the resulting jar files are installed into the .m2 repository.  Then when `mvn clean` is executed, my main app no longer complains about not being able to find my plugin.

#### M2 Repository

```
pizza@hut:~/maven/maven-test$ tree ~/.m2/repository/com/ecorp/
/somepath/.m2/repository/com/ecorp/
├── build-args
│   ├── 1.0-SNAPSHOT
│   │   ├── build-args-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
│   │   ├── build-args-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
│   │   ├── maven-metadata-local.xml
│   │   └── _remote.repositories
│   └── maven-metadata-local.xml
├── call-me
│   ├── 1.0-SNAPSHOT
│   │   ├── call-me-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
│   │   ├── call-me-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
│   │   ├── maven-metadata-local.xml
│   │   └── _remote.repositories
│   └── maven-metadata-local.xml
├── maven-metadata-local.xml
└── maven-test
    ├── 1.0-SNAPSHOT
    │   ├── maven-metadata-local.xml
    │   ├── maven-test-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
    │   └── _remote.repositories
    └── maven-metadata-local.xml
```

#### Clean

`mvn clean`

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO] 
[INFO] maven-test                                                         [pom]
[INFO] build-args Maven Plugin                                   [maven-plugin]
[INFO] call-me                                                            [jar]
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------< com.ecorp:maven-test >------------------------
[INFO] Building maven-test 1.0-SNAPSHOT                                   [1/3]
[INFO] --------------------------------[ pom ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:3.1.0:clean (default-clean) @ maven-test ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------< com.ecorp:build-args >------------------------
[INFO] Building build-args Maven Plugin 1.0-SNAPSHOT                      [2/3]
[INFO] ----------------------------[ maven-plugin ]----------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:3.1.0:clean (default-clean) @ build-args ---
[INFO] Deleting /somepath/maven-test/build-args/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------------------------< com.ecorp:call-me >--------------------------
[INFO] Building call-me 1.0-SNAPSHOT                                      [3/3]
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:3.1.0:clean (default-clean) @ call-me ---
[INFO] Deleting /somepath/maven-test/call-me/target
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary for maven-test 1.0-SNAPSHOT:
[INFO] 
[INFO] maven-test ......................................... SUCCESS [  0.159 s]
[INFO] build-args Maven Plugin ............................ SUCCESS [  0.037 s]
[INFO] call-me ............................................ SUCCESS [  0.015 s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  0.322 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-12-29T15:11:12-05:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```